# Data Frame alternately row binding in R

Tags: r, rbind

I have two Data Frames which have the exact the same columns and the same numer of rows.

I want to create a new Data Frame which contains both data frames but having rows binded alternately. It has to take one row from first Data Frame and one row from the second Data Frame untill the whole new Data Frame is built.

I tried to use `rbind()` without luck. I need a solution that doesn't include installing new R packages.

Picture for demonstration:

[image: DataFrame row binding]

EDIT: My number of rows are dynamic and can be very large. Furthermore, I need a solution that doesn't rely on column names since the strucutre is dynamic as well. I know the two data frames have the same structure each time.

Comment: Can you please share the sample dataset? Bcoz solution might vary from dataset to dataset. Easy way is to add odd number column for first `df` and even number column for second `df`. `Merge` these two `df` and sort by number.

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan My data set varies and column names are changing. But each time I have identical structure two dataset by column names and row size. I need a generic solution to combine identical data frames without a dependency on the column names.

Comment: *I tried to use rbind() without luck.* ... and why not? What is the undesired result or errors?

Comment: @Parfait Incorrect use I suppose. Should've used mapply like Sotos suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
rbind(df1,df2)[rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)),each=2)+c(0,nrow(df1)),]
```

Example:

```
set.seed(1)
df1<-as.data.frame(matrix(runif(20),ncol=4))
#         V1         V2        V3        V4
#1 0.2655087 0.89838968 0.2059746 0.4976992
#2 0.3721239 0.94467527 0.1765568 0.7176185
#3 0.5728534 0.66079779 0.6870228 0.9919061
#4 0.9082078 0.62911404 0.3841037 0.3800352
#5 0.2016819 0.06178627 0.7698414 0.7774452
df2<-as.data.frame(matrix(runif(20),ncol=4))
#         V1         V2        V3        V4
#1 0.9347052 0.38611409 0.4820801 0.6684667
#2 0.2121425 0.01339033 0.5995658 0.7942399
#3 0.6516738 0.38238796 0.4935413 0.1079436
#4 0.1255551 0.86969085 0.1862176 0.7237109
#5 0.2672207 0.34034900 0.8273733 0.4112744
rbind(df1,df2)[rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)),each=2)+c(0,nrow(df1)),]
#          V1         V2        V3        V4
#1  0.2655087 0.89838968 0.2059746 0.4976992
#6  0.9347052 0.38611409 0.4820801 0.6684667
#2  0.3721239 0.94467527 0.1765568 0.7176185
#7  0.2121425 0.01339033 0.5995658 0.7942399
#3  0.5728534 0.66079779 0.6870228 0.9919061
#8  0.6516738 0.38238796 0.4935413 0.1079436
#4  0.9082078 0.62911404 0.3841037 0.3800352
#9  0.1255551 0.86969085 0.1862176 0.7237109
#5  0.2016819 0.06178627 0.7698414 0.7774452
#10 0.2672207 0.34034900 0.8273733 0.4112744
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `mapply` with rbind, i.e.

```
d2 <- data.frame(a = c(4, 6, 8), b = c(letters[5:7]), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
d1 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(letters[1:3]), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

mapply(rbind, d1, d2)
#      a   b  
#[1,] "1" "a"
#[2,] "4" "e"
#[3,] "2" "b"
#[4,] "6" "f"
#[5,] "3" "c"
#[6,] "8" "g"
```

Comment: My number of rows are dynamic and can be very very large.

Comment: It doesn't matter how large it is

Comment: This might lose the data types of the original data frames.

Comment: @nicola indeed, they will have to restructure.

Comment: @nicola Thank you for the warning, indeed function as.matrix is being called and I lose types.

Answer (score 0):

with `tidyverse` and using @Sotos' data :

```
d2 <- data.frame(a = c(4, 6, 8), b = c(letters[5:7]), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
d1 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(letters[1:3]), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(tidyverse)
lst(d1,d2) %>%
  map(rowid_to_column) %>% # add rowid to both tables
  bind_rows %>%            # bind
  arrange(rowid) %>%       # sort by id
  select(-rowid)           # clean up

#   a b
# 1 1 a
# 2 4 e
# 3 2 b
# 4 6 f
# 5 3 c
# 6 8 g
```

And here is a base alternative

```
do.call(rbind,
        Map(rbind,
            split(d1,seq(nrow(d1))),
            split(d2,seq(nrow(d2))))
        )
#      a b
# 1.1  1 a
# 1.2  4 e
# 2.2  2 b
# 2.21 6 f
# 3.3  3 c
# 3.31 8 g
```